# Create importabile Java Class

Tags: java, import

I want to write my on importable class so that i can import it an not write it multiple times.

How can I make this an importable class:

```
    //SPACE START
    public static void space(int spacecount) {
        int spacepos = 1;
        while (spacepos <= spacecount) {
            System.out.println("");
            spacepos++;
        }
    }
    //SPACE END
    //HASH START
    public static int encrypt(String pass) {
        int total = 0;
        int  countone = 0;
        int  counttwo = 0;
        String charlist = "abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        for (int l = 0; l < pass.length(); l++) {
            countone = pass.charAt(l);
            counttwo = (charlist.indexOf(countone));
            counttwo++;
            total *= 17;
            total += counttwo; 
        }
        return total;
    }
    //HASH END
}
```

I think I import with: `myClassName.class`.

Comment: That doesn't look like a class to me.

Comment: Please have a look at the official [Getting Started](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/index.html) tutorial, which will give you an idea of how to organize and compile code, and what `.class` files are. After that, check out [Language Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html), in particular (when you feel ready), the section on "Packages".

Comment: @Arrem Wait, what? Classes can't be imported? Then why can I `import java.util.Math`? Is `Math` not a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add the class declaration line at the top of your code:

```
public class MyClass  {
```

Now it will compile  :).

Save it as `MyClass.java`, and add the line

```
package  my.package;
```

at the very top.

Compile it, and then, in another java file, import it with

```
import  my.package.MyClass;
```

and use it with

```
int i = MyClass.encrypt(password);
```

A much less common way to do it is to not use the import at all, and specify the fully-qualified name when using it:

```
int i = my.package.MyClass.encrypt(password);
```

---

Ideally, `MyClass.java` is stored in the directory as specified by your package line, such as

```
C:\java_code\my\package\MyClass.java
```

`MyClass` *must* be compiled such that `MyClass.class` is in your `CLASSPATH`, and *must* be in its package directory (`\my\package\MyClass.class`).

More information: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+CLASSPATH

(You should also take a look at the "Related Questions" on the upper right of this page.)

Comment: OK the compile has got it but how do i change the classpath. when i execute it like jout told it then it shows me the options of th command 'java' !

Comment: Assuming `MyClass.class` and `TheOtherClassUsingIt.class` are both correctly in the CLASSPATH, then call it on the command line with `java TheOtherClassUsingIt`. More information: https://www.google.com/search?q=compile+java+classpath+command+line and https://www.google.com/search?q=compile+java+classpath+command+line

Comment: ok now it tells me that the package not exist: `a.java:1: error: package my.ClassNew does not exist
import my.ClassNew.MyClass;
                  ^
a.java:5: error: cannot access MyClass
                MyClass.space(4);
                ^
  bad class file: .\MyClass.class
    class file contains wrong class: my.ClassNew.MyClass
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the cla
sspath.
2 errors` (class i want to write in is a.java)

Comment: I strongly recommend creating a new question, so you can get some fresh help.